# Share Eclipse config preferences

Tags: java, eclipse, preferences

I am new to Java and I am using Eclipse for writing code and when I began I made a lot of adjustments to make Eclipse better to me, like changing the font and font size, toggling line numbers apparition and all these things.

I wanna know if is there a way for me to share these preferences, in a file or directory for example, so when I need to use another computer I can just enable my preferences and not have to do all manual tweaks again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, you save your workspace preferences, and import them on machines you want to re-use em on.

right click on project -> export preferences.

Comment: @Shark That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pity that eclipse stores its preferences in the workspace so when switching to another one all the settings are lost.

You can first Export the preferences from the original workspace using File -> Export -> Preferences file. Then after the switch they can be imported back using File -> Import -> Preferences.

In case of another computer the only solution is to save the preferences file to a shared folder or use some service such as Dropbox to have the file under the auto-sync.